# Perforce command for getting files in a changelist in clients view

Tags: perforce

I am using the command `p4 describe <changelist>` but it gives the list of files under a changelist according to perforce server view. I want the list of files as in client's view. How to do that ? Can somehow `where` command be combined with `describe` to get the desired result ?

Comment: I think you'll need to write a script that grabs each file from the output of <code>describe</code> and runs it through <code>where</code> .  The </code>-ztags</code> flag will help you parse the output in a script.

Comment: I initially thought of that but just wanted to know if this can be done using only perforce specific command or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; is this about the way the file paths are displayed?  Are you looking for the client paths instead of the server/depot paths for the files in the changelist?  If you're running in Linux or something linux-like (like if you have sed), you could output the p4 describe to a file, then substitute based on your workspace mapping (substitute your client path for the depot path), then read out the file.  I don't think you can do this using p4 commands alone.

Comment: `p4 descripbe #changelist` gives the files in the changelist, how to get the difference in file for all the files with color highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this with something like:

```
p4 -c yourclient files //yourclient/...@=changelistnumber
```

?